# rails 4 - all javascripts being included at all times

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I understand the "why" part of "why do all js / css files get included in rails asset pipeline" as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137057/why-are-all-files-included-in-rails-asset-pipeline).

However, that's not always desirable, is it? For instance, I have a non-standard layout I use just to display items that require Google maps. I don't want all the external gmap libraries included on all pages-- it's not necessary and is just wasteful-- but if I don't include them on every page, the calls to the google api in the `map.js.coffee` files will throw errors.

Is there a way to force the `map.js.coffee` ONLY show on a `maps` view?

Comment: +1 Having a similar problem. I've fixed it with JS, checking if the parent element exists - if it does, I run the script for google map. But I'm not sure if that's the _right_ approach.

Comment: *"it's not necessary and is just wasteful"*, no, it's not wasteful. The whole point is that you have a single **cachable** bundle of JavaScript that only needs to be downloaded once, no matter how many pages you view on your site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine what the other answers suggested and other sources on the web advised, it seems like the best answer to this situation is to do the following:

Create subdirectories in the `assets/javascripts` and `assets/stylesheets` directories as well as `maps.js` and `maps.css` files. In my example above you'd have

```
app/
    assets/
        javascripts/
            application.js
            maps.js 
            maps/
            site/
        stylesheets/
            application.css
            maps.css
            maps/
            site/
```

Create any needed page-specific javascripts / stylesheets in those directories.

The `maps.js` file would look like:

```
//= require_tree ./maps
```

which will include all items in the maps directory  / subdirectories.

The `application.js` is the same but includes the "main" site resources as well as any site-specific items:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree ./site
```

Create a maps layout file called `views/layouts/maps.html.erb`, and in the layout file, use the `javascript_include_tag` to change which js / css file gets parsed for includes:

views/layouts/maps.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "maps", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "maps", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

Make sure the `MapsController` specifies the maps layout!

```
class MapsController < ApplicationController
    layout "maps"
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution, the `javascript_include_tag`:

```
# assets/javascripts/
#          user.js.coffee
#          form.js.coffee
#          map.js.coffee

# views/users/location.html.haml
= javascript_include_tag 'map'
```

But defining `//= require_tree .` in the `assets/application.js` does include all JS files, am I right?

So doing this would include the file twice, right?

---

**Update**: Following this RailsCast ( http://railscasts.com/episodes/279-understanding-the-asset-pipeline ) We might be able to create a public folder, containing all "shared" js files, and require it: `//= require_tree ./public`

Comment: @MrYoshiji-- I think this is the right approach. I think you'd want to create a couple directories in the `assets/javascripts` or `css` directories, maybe one for `map` and one for `everything` then use `//= require_tree map` in the `maps.js` file, and `//=require_tree everything` in the other. You'd also need to change the `layouts/map.html.erb` to have use `<%= javascript_include_tag "maps", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>`

Comment: Can you try it and tell me how it goes @user101289? I can't test it today, I have so many tasks at my job I can't try this option...

Answer (score 0):

Notice the line in application.html.sim:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
```

You want to include a different set of javascripts in a different layout map.html.slim, then create another javascript file, such as map.js.coffee, and in this file you included only files you need. Now the layout file needs to use this

```
= javascript_include_tag "map"
```